# In which module should the theme for an instant app be defined?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, android-module

After modularsing my app, the primary color changed from blue to orange. Hence, activity background, floating buttons, etc. changed.

The app theme is defined in the app module and uses @color/primary_color. The color is defined in the base module.

It looks like the primary color is picked up from the support library, not from my base module. Where is the correct place?

Comment: It turned out that the dependencies mixed up the resources. Two dependencies defined the same color. Moving one down in the dependency tree solved this issue.

Comment: Please, add it as an answer (and accept afterwards), so the question won't remain unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the dependencies mixed up the resources. Two dependencies could defined the same color. Moving one down in the dependency tree solves this issue.

Comment: Your issue may have been the result of not using distinct/unique names for your resources. See https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/faqs.html#project-structure "Can I share resources between features?"